# Testing django model clean method

Tags: django, testing, nose

I have a model with clean method that checks if either 2 fields are null, and if so it raises ValidationError

How can I perform a test (usually I'm using nose) to instance creation without making the test fail with error. I want to do some assertion to make sure that the creation of the instance has failed.

This is the clean method:

```
def clean(self):
    if not self.message and not self.image:
        raise ValidationError('You must provide either Message and/or '
                              'Image')
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [assertRaises()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises):

```
instance = YourModel()
self.assertRaises(ValidationError, instance.clean)
```